# QLPreviewController Detect when subView / PDF loads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using a [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display a quick look of a PDF file of roughly 200 KB, that includes multiple pages. My problem is that even using the `QLPreviewController` to render the PDF, there is still a 5-10 second delay in displaying the actual content of the PDF. (there is a blank white screen displayed for those seconds)

Is there an event / hook I can wire up so that I can show a Loading dialog until the full PDF preview has rendered? (i.e. show the loading dialog when the view first loads, then hide the loading dialog on a `subViewDidLoad` or equivalent)

Note: I'm using iOS 4.3.

**EDIT 5/23/2013:** Later versions of iOS have improved this control such that each page shows a loading icon over it by default. As such, there was no need for me to hook into any event to show my own Loading icon.

Comment: I have struggled with this problem for a long time. QLPreviewController takes a huge amount of time (and gigantic amounts of memory) even for simple PDFs. There is no hook provided by QLPC that will let you know that it is done.

Comment: It's incredible that there are no callbacks for this STILL.  What the hell is wrong with Apple?  We need this.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way to do that with the `QLPreviewController`.
the only thing you could do -- that's better for pdfs is: use a `UIWebView`